# How to pass variables to a external assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, memory, x86, calling-convention

How to pass a variable from a C program to a assembly function.

Example:

main.c:

```c
void main() {
  unsigned int passthis = 42
  extern asm_function();
  asm_function(passthis)
}
```

main.asm:

```
bits 32
global start
section .text
asm_function:
  ...
```

How do I access `passthis` within `asm_function`.

Edit: Probably should've mentioned i'm not using a OS, i'm compiling using a i686-elf cross compiler and am going to use it as a kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile your C into 32-bit code with the default GCC options (not `-mregparm=3` like the Linux kernel uses), then on function entry the first argument is on the stack just above the return address (at `[esp+4]`), but that offset changes after you `push` anything or move ESP around.

You can use `[ebp+8]` after setting up a traditional stack pointer (which doesn't change during the function even when ESP does).

For example, `int asm_function(int)` can be implemented as:

```
;bits 32              ; unneeded, nasm -felf32 implies this.
global asm_function   ; include asm_function in ELF .o symbol table for linking
section .text
asm_function:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]  ; return the first argument
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

For each parameter after this, just simply add another `4` (i.e. for the 2nd parameter, use `[ebp+12]`). As you can see, setting up EBP as a frame pointer adds a lot of overhead for tiny functions.

Some non-ELF systems/ABIs prepend a leading underscore to C symbol names, so you should declare both `asm_function` and `_asm_function` for your code to be roughly equivalent across these ABIs, like so:

```
global _asm_function
global asm_function  ; make both names of the function global
section .text
_asm_function:
asm_function:        ; make both symbols point to the same place
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Is this OS specific?

Comment: @charliehogger31 As far as I know, no.

Comment: The first argument is @ ESP+8, but the more common convention is to address arguments via EBP.  EBP+0 = Value of EBP when function was called, EBP+4 return address to caller.

Comment: I recommend *against* including `bits 32` in your NASM source files.  That lets you accidentally build with `nasm -felf64` and then link 32-bit machine code into a 64-bit binary.  (It's a bigger problem for GAS `.s` files which can be build with `gcc -c foo.s` which defaults to `-m64` on normal systems, so `.code32` is a terrible idea.  NASM's default is 16-bit flat binary so you always need a `-f` option except for that.)

Answer (score 2):

x86 has probably a handful of different calling conventions.  It depends on a number of things, like windows vs. linux, and on what compiler environment you're using, 32-bit vs. 64-bit, etc..

Best probably to look at the output of the compiler you're using to see how the parameter is being passed, and do the corresponding appropriate way of accepting the parameter in your assembly.  So if it is pushed on the stack then expect it there, if it is passed in a register, expect it there...

You can look at the output using a disassembler, or using a debugger.

Comment: It's probably not 64-bit x86 as evidenced by the `bits 32` in the asm code.